# How to export a program with an alternate extension in SCons on Windows

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, scons

I am using SCons to cross-compile embedded code using a Windows host. My colleagues are running Ubuntu. We have many lines in our SConscript files like the following:

```
prog = env.Program("progname.elf", obj, libs)
```

On Ubuntu this works fine. On Windows it fails with the following error:

```
scons: *** An executable should have exactly one target with the suffix: .exe
```

The best answer I have managed to find so far is to name the file `progname_elf.exe` and rename it after the fact, but it seems like SCons ought to be able to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
prog = env.Program("progname.elf", obj, libs)
```

in your SConscripts should look like this:

```
prog = env.Program("progname", obj, libs)
```

. Then you could set the variable "$PROGSUFFIX" to ".elf" under Posix systems. This would be the SConsish way of dealing with this...see also [How to force scons to generate binary file with .bin extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833937/how-to-force-scons-to-generate-binary-file-with-bin-extension/26834311) .

Comment: SConsish?? Isnt there something similar to Pythonic for SCons? ;) How about Sconsy?

Comment: Possible (I'm not a native speaker), at some point we should setup a SCons Naming Task Force...or somethin'. :)